# player MP3 com Python

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

Eu não sei quase nada de programação e por isso eu venho estudando novas possibilidades, como POO e afins.
Recentemente me deu uma vontade de tentar aprender Interface Gráfica e também de criar um player MP3, isto tudo em Python (tudo ontem).
Eu comecei a procurar meios de satisfazer o meu desejo e resolvi unir os dois em um só projeto, porém eu estou com um sério problema, **não estou conseguindo avançar e nem retroceder uma música em meu player.**

Não sei se eu fiz algo de errado, porém já tentei de tudo e não consegui resolver este pequenos e importuno problema.
Estarei deixando o meu fonte abaixo para que possam analisar.

```
from pygame  import mixer # Load the required library
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import *

musicas = []

class Reprodutor :
    def __init__ (self):
       pass

    def escolher ():
        selecionar = askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/",
                           filetypes =(("Arquivo de audio", "*.mp3"),("All Files","*.*")),
                           title = "Selecione as musicas"
                           )
        musicas.append(selecionar)
        return musicas

    def reproduzir ():
        """ 
        mixer.init()
        mixer.music.load('C:/Users/Andreza/Music/Jeff The Killer Theme Song Piano Version Sweet Dreams Are Made Of Screams.mp3')
        mixer.music.play()
        """

        mixer.init()

        for item in musicas:
            musica_atual = mixer.music.load(item)
            musica_atual = mixer.music.play()

    def parar ():
        musica_atual = mixer.music.stop()

    def pausar ():
        musica_atual = mixer.music.pause()

    def retomar ():
        musica_atual = mixer.music.unpause() #Continua da local pausado


    def proxima ():
        for item in range(len(musicas)):
            musica_atual = mixer.music.load(musicas[item])
            musica_atual = mixer.music.play()
            item += 1


    def anterior ():
        for item in range(len(musicas)):
            musica_atual = mixer.music.load(musicas[item])
            musica_atual = mixer.music.play()
            item -= 1 



player = Reprodutor

janela =Tk()

janela.title("REPRODUTOR - FÉLIX LICHT") #Titulo

#Esta parte é que está com problemas
bt_escolher = Button(janela, width=20, text="ADICIONAR MUSICAS", command=player.escolher)
bt_proxima  = Button(janela, width=10, text="PROXIMA",            command=player.proxima)
bt_anterior = Button(janela, width=10, text="ANTERIOR",          command=player.anterior)

bt_escolher.place (x=10,  y=50 )
bt_proxima.place  (x=170, y=50)
bt_anterior.place (x=270, y=50)



bt_play    = Button(janela, width=10, text="PLAY",    command=player.reproduzir)
bt_pause   = Button(janela, width=10, text="PAUSAR",  command=player.pausar)
bt_stop    = Button(janela, width=10, text="PARAR",   command=player.parar)
bt_return  = Button(janela, width=10, text="RETOMAR", command=player.retomar)

bt_play.place   (x=10,  y=0)
bt_pause.place  (x=110, y=0)
bt_stop.place   (x=210, y=0)
bt_return.place (x=310, y=0)

janela.geometry("1280x720+450+350")
janela.mainloop()
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar, ficarei grato.

**Obrigado**

**Editada:**

Após a modificação, que foi realizada com base na primeira resposta do post, o programa começou a passar a música e voltar a música, porém ele faz este procedimento apenas uma vez.

Eu tentei criar um sistema de controle, onde o item do for, seria equiparado ao ultimo elemento da lista, e se você verdadeiro ele voltaria para o valor 0 da lita, porém nem isto funcionou.

================================================================================

```
from pygame  import mixer # Load the required library
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import *

musicas = []
TAM     = len(musicas)

class Reprodutor :
    def __init__ (self):
       pass

    def escolher ():
        selecionar = askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/",
                           filetypes =(("Arquivo de audio", "*.mp3"),("All Files","*.*")),
                           title = "Selecione as musicas",
                           #multiple = True
                           )
        musicas.append(selecionar)


        for i in musicas:
            print(i, end=" ")
            print()
        print()


        return musicas

    def reproduzir ():
        mixer.init()

        for item in musicas:
            musica_atual = mixer.music.load(item)
            musica_atual = mixer.music.play()

    def parar ():
        musica_atual = mixer.music.stop()

    def pausar ():
        musica_atual = mixer.music.pause()

    def retomar ():
        musica_atual = mixer.music.unpause() #Continua da local pausado

#Próximo e Anterior com Modificações realizadas com base na resposta do Antony Gabriel
    def proxima ():
        for item in range(len(musicas)):

            item += 1
            musica_atual = mixer.music.load(musicas[item])  
            musica_atual = mixer.music.play() 

    def anterior ():
        for item in range(len(musicas)):
            item -= 1 
            musica_atual = mixer.music.load(musicas[item])
            musica_atual = mixer.music.play()


player = Reprodutor

janela =Tk()

janela.title("REPRODUTOR - FÉLIX LICHT") #Titulo

#Esta parte é que está com problemas
bt_escolher = Button(janela, width=20, text="ADICIONAR MUSICAS",  command=player.escolher)
bt_proxima  = Button(janela, width=10, text="PROXIMA",            command=player.proxima)
bt_anterior = Button(janela, width=10, text="ANTERIOR",           command=player.anterior)

bt_escolher.place (x=10,  y=50 )
bt_proxima.place  (x=170, y=50)
bt_anterior.place (x=270, y=50)



bt_play    = Button(janela, width=10, text="PLAY",    command=player.reproduzir)
bt_pause   = Button(janela, width=10, text="PAUSAR",  command=player.pausar)
bt_stop    = Button(janela, width=10, text="PARAR",   command=player.parar)
bt_return  = Button(janela, width=10, text="RETOMAR", command=player.retomar)

bt_play.place   (x=10,  y=0)
bt_pause.place  (x=110, y=0)
bt_stop.place   (x=210, y=0)
bt_return.place (x=310, y=0)

janela.geometry("410x80+450+350")
janela.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4):

Engraçado, eu só precisei mover o `item += 1` e `item -= 1` para cima, e funcionou tranquilo. Era só isso mesmo, você fez tudo certinho.

```
def proxima ():
    for item in range(len(musicas)):
        item += 1
        musica_atual = mixer.music.load(musicas[item])
        musica_atual = mixer.music.play()



def anterior ():
    for item in range(len(musicas)):
        item -= 1 
        musica_atual = mixer.music.load(musicas[item])
        musica_atual = mixer.music.play()
```

**Para resolver o problema de avanço eu mudei para isso:**

O problema era que a variável `item` estava indo para -1, que era impossível de encontrar uma música,por isso não voltava. E o outro problema é que ele(`item`) também estava incrementando o valor demais, indo para uma música inexistente, por isso não avançava.

Eu também tirei os `for`, preferi por usar uma variável chamada item.

Ao que parece resolvi a maioria dos problemas. O único problema que não consegui resolver e que aparece as vezes é que ele não lê a música número 1 ( Que seria a segunda ), mas não é sempre.

Espero ter ajudado.

Segue o código de onde modifiquei :

```
def proxima ():
    global item #Usando uma variável de fora
    item += 1
    #print(item) # Utilizei para checar o que havia de errado.
    try:
        musica_atual = mixer.music.load(musicas[item])
        musica_atual = mixer.music.play()
    except IndexError: # Se o Index nao existir, isso vai impedir que o valor de item incremente.
        item -= 1



def anterior ():
    global item
    if item - 1 == -1: # Se for -1 ele volta não decrementa, ficando em 0.
        pass
    else:
        item -= 1
    #print(item)
    musica_atual = mixer.music.load(musicas[item])
    musica_atual = mixer.music.play()
```

Também mudei a função `escolher()`, notei que algumas vezes ficavam uns `''` na lista, o que fazia que o programa não avançasse/retrocedesse, e coloquei para iniciar na área de trabalho, que para mim ficava melhor (minhas músicas ficam no desktop), então fiz isso:

```
def escolher ():
    selecionar = askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/Users/%user%/desktop",
                       filetypes =(("Arquivo de audio", "*.mp3"),("All Files","*.*")),
                       title = "Selecione as musicas"
                       )
    if selecionar == '': # Se tiver '' ele não faz nada ( pass )
        pass
    else:
        musicas.append(selecionar)
```

Comment: eu queria agradecer pela ajuda e também comentar que:

Comment: com o código a cima, eu só consigo voltar a música uma vez, e quando eu tento adiantar, da erro de index

Comment: mas com o esqueleto a cima, acho que posso tentar resolver

Comment: Pronto, alterei minha resposta. Creio que resolvi o seu problema.

Comment: Mais uma coisa, aonde você referenciou o item?

Comment: vou mandar uma print, calma

Comment: http://prntscr.com/f6b5p3 print usando light shot

Comment: Ah sim, verdade, esqueci de dizer. Eu coloquei embaixo da variável musicas, lá em cima. Com valor inicial 0.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado XD me salvou mesmo ^^. eu estava preso aqui e não sabia o que fazer, eu ate tinha tentado usar global, mas não conseguir ir adiante. Agora eu vou modificar o progama para selecionar varias músicas de uma só vez, salvar o caminho em um TXT de cada música, e depois acessar diretamente ^^

Comment: mais uma vez, muito obigado

Comment: Disponha :), achei bacana o seu programa. Boa sorte.

Answer (score -3):

Vc tbm pode usar a Biblioteca playsound!

Só importar assim:

```
 from playsound import playsound
```

E depois fazer tocar o arquivo mp3 q vc quiser assim:

```
playsound('nome_do_arquivo_mp3', block=false)
```

É importante colocar o `block=false` pq se não só vai tocar a musica e não vai rodar o programa!

E se vc quiser fazer interfaces gráficas, use a biblioteca "PySimpleGUI"!